# How to cache a cursor object?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, caching, cursor

I have a huge database (SQLite Engine) in my application, I need to run a query once a week and cache the cursor of that query to re-use it later, So I wrote the following function to save my cursor through `ObjectStream` but I'm not able to load it via `ObjectInputStream` because it's not serializable!!!

Any ideas on how to accomplish this functionality?

```
public Cursor getCachedCursor(ReaderState state, String[] allowedColumns
        , String sortType, int limit) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    File cacheFilePath = CacheManager.getCachePath(state.toString() + ".cached");
    Cursor mCursor = null;

    try
    {
        if (cacheFilePath == null)
        { 
             FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFilePath);
             ObjectOutputStream mObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(mFileOutputStream);

             mObjectOutputStream.writeObject(mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, allowedColumns, null, null
                     , null, null, sortType, String.valueOf(limit)));

             mObjectOutputStream.close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(cacheFilePath);
        ObjectInputStream mObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(mFileInputStream);

        mCursor = (Cursor) mObjectInputStream.readObject();

        mObjectInputStream.close();
    }

    return mCursor;
}
```

Comment: What do you call a "huge database"? What is it? A file? An SQL engine? Other?

Comment: @fge It is SQLite engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to run a query once a week and cache the cursor of that query to re-use it later

A once-a-week query would seem to be much better suited to simply re-run the query, rather than caching the results, since those results may become stale if the database is modified during that week.

> Any ideas on how to accomplish this functionality?

Manually iterate over the `Cursor` and save all columns of all rows to the file format of your choice (e.g., JSON).

Comment: Thanks Mr.Murphy, Is it impossible to cache a cursor?

Comment: @iSun: A `Cursor` is designed to be an **in-memory** representation of the results of a database query. The "cache" is the database itself. If you wish to persist the `Cursor` contents separately from the database, that's your problem to solve.

Comment: How about [ContentQueryMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentQueryMap.html)?

Comment: @iSun: What about it? You will still need to manually iterate over that object's contents and write them to the file format of your choice.